# In which languages can I estimate a VMA model?

Tags: time-series, arima, estimators, software

In which languages/environments are there tools to estimate a [vector moving average model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model#Generalizations) of a given order? That is, given $q\in\mathbb{N}$ and a multivariate time series $y_t\in\mathbb{R}^d$, $t=1,\dots,T$, a function that returns best-fitting (in some sense, ML for instance) matrices $\Theta_i\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ such that $y_t$ is generated by the process

$$y_t=u_t+\Theta_1 u_{t-1} + \dots + \Theta_q u_{t-q},$$

where $u_i\in\mathbb{R}^d$ are iid random variables (for instance, multivariate Gaussians)?

I'd be especially interested in open-source languages such as Python or Julia.

Comment: "MTS" package in R, see functions `VMA`, `VMACpp`, `VMAe`, `VMAoder`, `VMAs`.

Comment: Thanks! Are there other alternatives? I know Mathematica had a time series package, which has now been discontinued, for instance.

Comment: I am only using R, so I cannot comment on other statistical packages. In R there are also a few other packages that can do VARMA models, I'd recommend to take a look around. "dse" may be one of them, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Can you please explain in your post (as an edit) what is VMA?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I have expanded the acronym and linked to the closest Wikipedia page that I can find. I hope this is sufficient. Note that the rest of my question (the sentence after "That is") is already a self-contained definition of what a VMA model is.